# How to create a list with different type of data using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list, arraylist, tuples

I need to create a list with different datatypes element, for example:

```
{{10, 10}, "IT", 1, "Test", {100, 100}, "Test"}
```

respectively:

```
{object, string, integer, string, object, string}
```

I have tried declaring it as list of objects or  using `Tuple(Of Object, String, Integer, String, Object, String)`
but when I give them the values,

> "Array initializer has too few dimensions"

error occurs.

The class where the variable is declared:

```
Public Class SignatureResponse

    Public signature As Tuple(Of Object, String, Integer, String, Object, String)

    Sub New()
        Me.signature = Nothing

    End Sub

    Sub New(ByVal signature As Tuple(Of Object, String, Integer, String, Object, String))
        Me.signature = signature
    End Sub
End Class
```

The class to which I use the parameter and assign the values:

```
Public Class Signature
      Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()>
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False, XmlSerializeString:=False)>
    Public Function SendIdDocuments(ByVal idDocument As String, ByVal content As String, ByVal userId As String)
       Dim respDocs As New SignatureResponse
                respDocs.signature = {{10, 10}, "IT", 1, "Testing", {100, 100}, "Test Signature"}
             'Other part of development
            JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(respDocs)

        Return JSONString
    End Function

End Class
```

I am sending just the more important part of the code, they are more parameters used that works perfectly, except this one.

Error:
[image: Error]

Any help please?

Comment: The tuple approach looks like it would make sense, if the elements will always be in that order by type.  Can you show the code that failed?

Comment: You need a class object to hold your values Then use a `List(Of class)`.

Comment: I have edited the question, I wish I am more clear.

Comment: Wow.. `(Object, String, Integer, String, Object, String)` as a Tuple is pretty hard to understand. Especially in 6 months when you are on vacation or left the company. I would create a class with proper property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the old Tuple syntax as above then you can't create a new one in the way you've shown.  You have to do:

```
    respDocs.signature =
        New Tuple(Of Object, String, Integer, String, Object, String)({10, 10}, "IT", 1, "Testing", {100, 100}, "Test Signature")
```

Comment: There is also a [better syntax if you're targeting .NET Framework 4.7 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples#visual-basic-tuples-and-tuples-in-the-net-framework), although it's a different type of tuple altogether.